# Is every point of every open set $E \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ a limit point of $E$? [Proof Verification]

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Classic problem from Baby Rudin that I want to see if I proved correctly:

> Is every point of every open set $E \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ a limit point of $E$ ?

Solution:

Suppose $E$ is open and there exists a point $p \in E$ that is not a limit point.

Since $p$ is not a limit point,

$\Rightarrow$ there exists nbhd $N_r(p)$ of set $E$ such thtat for all $q \neq p$, $q \notin E$

But given that $E$ is open, this means $p$ is an interior point of $E$.

$\Rightarrow$ there exists a nbhds $N_\epsilon(q) \subset N_\delta(p) \subset E$ such that $q \in E$ and $q\neq p$

if we take **min**{$r, \delta$} we have a ball around $p$ where $N_\epsilon(q) \subset B_{min(r,\delta)}(p)$

$\Rightarrow$ there exists points $q \in E$ ,$q\neq p$, and $ q\in B_{min(r,\delta)}(p)$

This is a contradiction because $p$ was assumed to be a limit point

Q.E.D

Comment: For other spaces than $\mathbb{R}^2$ this property isn't true. That is why you need to use that open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are unions discs, and each disc contains many points.

Comment: @cactus So it's false for $\mathbb R?$

Comment: For **some** other spaces than $\mathbb R^2$ this property isn't true. But, for $\mathbb R$ and more generally for $\mathbb R^n$, it is indeed true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you have shown a contradiction. It seems like you have shown that there exists a neighborhood $N_r(p)$ such that all points in that neighborhood (other than $p$ itself) are outside $E$, and there exists a neighborhood $N_\delta(p)$ such that some point in the neighborhood is in $E$. But the two neighborhoods need not be the same, so what is the contradiction?

You're very close though.

Comment: I edited my solution a little. I think that fixes it up....

Comment: @dc3rd I still don't see what the contradiction is. Perhaps you should try to be more explicit about what the contradiction is.

Comment: @dc3rd You still haven't used the shape of neighborhoods in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you add to the last implication that $N_{\delta}(p)$ contains a ball $\{x:\ \|x-p\|<s_1\}$, and therefore, contains many points of $E$ besides $p$. Then you can compare it with another ball $\{x:\ \|x-p\|<s_2\}$ contained in $N_{r}(p)$ which should only contain $p$ from $E$. Using the particular shape of open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is necessary, since in an space like $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$, with the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{2\}$ is open but its point is not a limit point.

Comment: @cactus that would be the direct method of the proof, but I'm trying to do it via contradiction...

Comment: @dc3rd No. Using that $p$ is not limit you get a ball in which the only point of $E$ is $p$. Using that $E$ is open you get a ball in which all of its points are in $E$ and there are many points of besides $p$. The smaller of the two balls has at the same time many points of $E$ and only $p$. That is the contradiction.

Comment: @cactus I edited my solution. Could you have a look and give me your thoughts? I tried not to replicate exactly how you said it word for word and allow myself to think it through.

Comment: @dc3rd It is still awkward, because there are little portions that are not really true. For example, if $\min(r,\delta)=r$, then maybe $N_\epsilon(q)$ is not inside $B_{\min(r,\delta)}(p)$. Also, there is the notation $B_s(p)$ supposedly meaning a ball of radius $s$ and centered at $p$, but then what is the $r$ in $N_r(p)$? A neighborhood that contains a ball of radius $r$? If you suspect that the notation is not very general, it is safer to define it, just to be clear. Very likely, if you draw a picture that will guide you on how to compose the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You try to prove your statement by contradiction. While a direct proof in this case is easier, you have made some progress in your proof. Your idea is correct but you have to be more careful with your quantifiers.

Comment: I've seen some of the direct proofs. I'm curious as to why you feel they are easier? When I attempted to create this proof the direct methods never even occurred to me.

Comment: You have a very strong hypothesis in this case, namely the set being open and the topology is metric. Why not use it directly to show that every point is a limit point?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, every $x \in E$ is interior to $E$, hence there is a ball $B(x, r)$ with $r > 0$ contained in $E$. For each neighborhood of $x$, it intersects with $B(x,r) \setminus \{r\}$ at least at one point, so $x$ must be a limit point.